# How to get the properties from XML using Jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've already tried some approaches but seems to be something on the way I'm doing it.
I created a simple Java class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "TRANSACTION")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CanonicalPropertyJaxb {

    @XmlAttribute
    protected String edbt;

    public String getEdbt() {
        return edbt;
    }

    public void setEdbt(String edbt) {
        this.edbt = edbt;
    }



}
```

And that's the XML I receive. I need this XML to generate the Java object and the Java object to generate this same XML whenever I need. So I started just trying to get the EDBT property from the TRANSACTION tag, but It's always returning null.

```
<TRANSACTION ETYPE='JDEMCU' EDUS='IPAAS_ADM' EDBT='16919' EDTN='0' EDLN='2.000' EKEY='IPAAS_ADM-16919-0-2.000'>     <TABLE_1 NAME='F0006Z1' TYPE='1'>       <FORMAT_TABLE_F0006Z1 SEQ="1">         <COLUMN_EDUS>IPAAS_ADM</COLUMN_EDUS>         <COLUMN_EDBT>16919</COLUMN_EDBT>         <COLUMN_EDTN>0</COLUMN_EDTN>         <COLUMN_EDLN>2.000</COLUMN_EDLN>         <COLUMN_EDCT></COLUMN_EDCT>         <COLUMN_TYTN>JDEMCU</COLUMN_TYTN>         <COLUMN_EDFT></COLUMN_EDFT>         <COLUMN_EDDT />         <COLUMN_DRIN>2</COLUMN_DRIN>         <COLUMN_EDDL>0</COLUMN_EDDL>         <COLUMN_EDSP></COLUMN_EDSP>         <COLUMN_PNID></COLUMN_PNID>         <COLUMN_TNAC>02</COLUMN_TNAC>         <COLUMN_MCU>200</COLUMN_MCU>         <COLUMN_STYL>CB</COLUMN_STYL>         <COLUMN_DC>FINANCEREPORTTESTBSBU</COLUMN_DC>         <COLUMN_LDM>3</COLUMN_LDM>         <COLUMN_CO>00200</COLUMN_CO>         <COLUMN_AN8>0</COLUMN_AN8>         <COLUMN_AN8O>0</COLUMN_AN8O>         <COLUMN_CNTY></COLUMN_CNTY>         <COLUMN_ADDS></COLUMN_ADDS>         <COLUMN_FMOD></COLUMN_FMOD>         <COLUMN_DL01>Finance Report Test BS BU</COLUMN_DL01>         <COLUMN_DL02></COLUMN_DL02>         <COLUMN_DL03></COLUMN_DL03>         <COLUMN_DL04></COLUMN_DL04>         <COLUMN_RP01>DOM</COLUMN_RP01>         <COLUMN_RP02>CAN</COLUMN_RP02>         <COLUMN_RP03>NAA</COLUMN_RP03>         <COLUMN_RP04>NAA</COLUMN_RP04>         <COLUMN_RP05>NAA</COLUMN_RP05>         <COLUMN_RP06>ZZ</COLUMN_RP06>         <COLUMN_RP07>NAA</COLUMN_RP07>         <COLUMN_RP08>NAA</COLUMN_RP08>         <COLUMN_RP09>NAA</COLUMN_RP09>         <COLUMN_RP10>NAA</COLUMN_RP10>         <COLUMN_RP11>NAA</COLUMN_RP11>         <COLUMN_RP12>NAA</COLUMN_RP12>         <COLUMN_RP13>NAA</COLUMN_RP13>         <COLUMN_RP14>NAA</COLUMN_RP14>         <COLUMN_RP15>NAA</COLUMN_RP15>         <COLUMN_RP16>NAA</COLUMN_RP16>         <COLUMN_RP17>NAA</COLUMN_RP17>         <COLUMN_RP18>NAA</COLUMN_RP18>         <COLUMN_RP19>NAA</COLUMN_RP19>         <COLUMN_RP20>NAA</COLUMN_RP20>         <COLUMN_RP21>NAA</COLUMN_RP21>         <COLUMN_RP22>NAA</COLUMN_RP22>         <COLUMN_RP23>NAA</COLUMN_RP23>         <COLUMN_RP24></COLUMN_RP24>         <COLUMN_RP25></COLUMN_RP25>         <COLUMN_RP26></COLUMN_RP26>         <COLUMN_RP27></COLUMN_RP27>         <COLUMN_RP28></COLUMN_RP28>         <COLUMN_RP29></COLUMN_RP29>         <COLUMN_RP30></COLUMN_RP30>         <COLUMN_TA></COLUMN_TA>         <COLUMN_TXJS>0</COLUMN_TXJS>         <COLUMN_TXA1></COLUMN_TXA1>         <COLUMN_EXR1></COLUMN_EXR1>         <COLUMN_TC01></COLUMN_TC01>         <COLUMN_TC02></COLUMN_TC02>         <COLUMN_TC03></COLUMN_TC03>         <COLUMN_TC04></COLUMN_TC04>         <COLUMN_TC05></COLUMN_TC05>         <COLUMN_TC06></COLUMN_TC06>         <COLUMN_TC07></COLUMN_TC07>         <COLUMN_TC08></COLUMN_TC08>         <COLUMN_TC09></COLUMN_TC09>         <COLUMN_TC10></COLUMN_TC10>         <COLUMN_ND01></COLUMN_ND01>         <COLUMN_ND02></COLUMN_ND02>         <COLUMN_ND03></COLUMN_ND03>         <COLUMN_ND04></COLUMN_ND04>         <COLUMN_ND05></COLUMN_ND05>         <COLUMN_ND06></COLUMN_ND06>         <COLUMN_ND07></COLUMN_ND07>         <COLUMN_ND08></COLUMN_ND08>         <COLUMN_ND09></COLUMN_ND09>         <COLUMN_ND10></COLUMN_ND10>         <COLUMN_CC01>N</COLUMN_CC01>         <COLUMN_CC02>N</COLUMN_CC02>         <COLUMN_CC03>N</COLUMN_CC03>         <COLUMN_CC04>N</COLUMN_CC04>         <COLUMN_CC05>N</COLUMN_CC05>         <COLUMN_CC06>N</COLUMN_CC06>         <COLUMN_CC07>N</COLUMN_CC07>         <COLUMN_CC08>N</COLUMN_CC08>         <COLUMN_CC09>N</COLUMN_CC09>         <COLUMN_CC10>N</COLUMN_CC10>         <COLUMN_PECC></COLUMN_PECC>         <COLUMN_ALS>6</COLUMN_ALS>         <COLUMN_ISS>T</COLUMN_ISS>         <COLUMN_GLBA></COLUMN_GLBA>         <COLUMN_ALCL>00</COLUMN_ALCL>         <COLUMN_LMTH></COLUMN_LMTH>         <COLUMN_LF>1.0000</COLUMN_LF>         <COLUMN_OBJ1></COLUMN_OBJ1>         <COLUMN_OBJ2></COLUMN_OBJ2>         <COLUMN_OBJ3></COLUMN_OBJ3>         <COLUMN_SUB1></COLUMN_SUB1>         <COLUMN_TOU>.00</COLUMN_TOU>         <COLUMN_SBLI></COLUMN_SBLI>         <COLUMN_ANPA>0</COLUMN_ANPA>         <COLUMN_CT>FF</COLUMN_CT>         <COLUMN_CERT>N</COLUMN_CERT>         <COLUMN_MCUS></COLUMN_MCUS>         <COLUMN_BTYP></COLUMN_BTYP>         <COLUMN_PC>.00</COLUMN_PC>         <COLUMN_PCA>.00</COLUMN_PCA>         <COLUMN_PCC>.00</COLUMN_PCC>         <COLUMN_INTA></COLUMN_INTA>         <COLUMN_INTL></COLUMN_INTL>         <COLUMN_D1J />         <COLUMN_D2J />         <COLUMN_D3J />         <COLUMN_D4J />         <COLUMN_D5J />         <COLUMN_D6J />         <COLUMN_FPDJ />         <COLUMN_CAC>.00</COLUMN_CAC>         <COLUMN_PAC>.00</COLUMN_PAC>         <COLUMN_EEO>N</COLUMN_EEO>         <COLUMN_ERC></COLUMN_ERC>         <COLUMN_USER>IPAAS_ADM</COLUMN_USER>         <COLUMN_PID>ER0006Z1E</COLUMN_PID>         <COLUMN_UPMJ>2016/12/15</COLUMN_UPMJ>         <COLUMN_JOBN>DJDELOG02</COLUMN_JOBN>         <COLUMN_UPMT>144810</COLUMN_UPMT>         <COLUMN_URCD></COLUMN_URCD>         <COLUMN_URAT>.00</COLUMN_URAT>         <COLUMN_URDT />         <COLUMN_URAB>0</COLUMN_URAB>         <COLUMN_URRF></COLUMN_URRF>         <COLUMN_TORG></COLUMN_TORG>         <COLUMN_RP31></COLUMN_RP31>         <COLUMN_RP32></COLUMN_RP32>         <COLUMN_RP33></COLUMN_RP33>         <COLUMN_RP34></COLUMN_RP34>         <COLUMN_RP35></COLUMN_RP35>         <COLUMN_RP36></COLUMN_RP36>         <COLUMN_RP37></COLUMN_RP37>         <COLUMN_RP38></COLUMN_RP38>         <COLUMN_RP39></COLUMN_RP39>         <COLUMN_RP40></COLUMN_RP40>         <COLUMN_RP41></COLUMN_RP41>         <COLUMN_RP42></COLUMN_RP42>         <COLUMN_RP43></COLUMN_RP43>         <COLUMN_RP44></COLUMN_RP44>         <COLUMN_RP45></COLUMN_RP45>         <COLUMN_RP46></COLUMN_RP46>         <COLUMN_RP47></COLUMN_RP47>         <COLUMN_RP48></COLUMN_RP48>         <COLUMN_RP49></COLUMN_RP49>         <COLUMN_RP50></COLUMN_RP50>         <COLUMN_AN8GCA1>0</COLUMN_AN8GCA1>         <COLUMN_AN8GCA2>0</COLUMN_AN8GCA2>         <COLUMN_AN8GCA3>0</COLUMN_AN8GCA3>         <COLUMN_AN8GCA4>0</COLUMN_AN8GCA4>         <COLUMN_AN8GCA5>0</COLUMN_AN8GCA5>       </FORMAT_TABLE_F0006Z1>     </TABLE_1>   </TRANSACTION>
```

What's the right way to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

JAXB is case sensitive. So either change the field to `EDBT`, or add the uppercase name to `@XmlAttribute(name="EDBT")`.

Comment: Already tried that as well. Still not getting the expected result. Getting null there. Also tried to modify the attribute to match the name on the XML (EDBT upper case), and still the same result.

Comment: @Igor How do you call jaxb? Sure that you call it on exactly that xml? If there is an additional element around transaction, (depending on how you call jaxb) you will get a none null `CanonicalPropertyJaxb` with null edbt field.

Comment: I'm using mule, and I'm setting this exact XML hard coded for now to test. I'm able to get other attributes, but not the properties from the tag specifically.

Comment: @Igor from a jaxb point it is valid, the problem must be somewhere in mule or they way you embedd it into mule

Comment: That's weird because I can get information from TABLE_1 for instance. but not from the properties into the TRANSACTION tag.